# open a dialog behind a modal dialog or after it is closed

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application which has several background tasks running in non-GUI threads which may time to time require some user interaction so they send signal to the main thread and the corresponding slot creates a dialog and shows it to the user. Meanwhile the task thread is waiting in a blocking event loop. Once the user answers the dialog and closes it, the task event loop is signaled to quit and the task resumes.

There is however a problem. In the GUI thread I can still use the application which time to time shows some modal dialogs. When there is a modal dialog already shown and then the background tasks requests another dialog to be opened, this task-related dialog is displayed in front of the modal dialog. But this new dialog is not modal and the modal dialog is hidden behind it. The non-modal one therefore is not responsive, the application feels like it got stuck.

My idea was to display the new dialog always behind the modal dialog, which I believe I can get with `QApplication::activeModalWidget()`. But I do not know how to do this. How can I show a dialog behind another dialog but still in front of the main window (which is a parent of both dialogs)? I tried to call `QApplication::activeModalWidget()->activateWindow()` after I show the non-modal one but his causes blinking of windows and moreover I can still click into the new non-modal dialog hiding the modal one. So this is not a perfect solution.

Or do you see any other solution?

Maybe I could implement a queue of dialogs, and once there is any modal dialog visible, then the new background task-related dialog would not be shown, only enqueued and shown once the modal dialog is closed. However this feels more fragile solution to me.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I redefined the question by adding "or after it is closed" becasue this works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which seems to work well and which shows the non-modal dialog only after the modal dialog is closed.

```
QWidget *nonModalDialog = ... // creates the non-modal dialog
nonModalDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
QWidget *modalDialog = qApp->activeModalWidget();
if (modalDialog == nullptr)
{
    // no modal dialog, we can show the non-modal one now
    dialog->show();
}
else
{
    // we must wait until the modal one is closed
    QObject::connect(modalDialog, &QWidget::destroyed, nonModalDialog, &QWidget::show);
}
```

This seems simple and robust.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [QWidget::raise()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise). You should be able to use `QApplication::activeModalWidget()->raise()` after calling `dialog->show()` on your non-modal dialog.

If you're getting into situations where you have multiple modal and non-modal dialogs, all launched in different order, this might not be enough to solve the problem. You might raise one modal dialog only to have others behind other non-modal dialogs and end up stuck again. You should consider keeping a reference to the collection of modal dialogs that are currently active so that you can make sure they are always on top of the non-modal dialogs.

Comment: This definitely is an interesting solution, but the effect is the same as the one which I mention with calling `QApplication::activeModalWidget()->activateWindow()`. The modal dialog will be raised, but I still will be able to click into the new non-modal dialog and it will activate it (though its child widgets will not be clickable clickable) and hiding the modal dialog. This is strange because modal should be modal disallowing activating another dialog. This is possibly a bug in Qt.